# Chrome OS in VMPlayer

Tags: google-chrome-os, vmware-player

Trying to create a virtual machine using VMPlayer, I discovered that as the Chrome OS is now a Release Candidate, it is only available here: http://www.getchrome.eu/download.php

However, there is no .vmdk download but "Live CD" and "USB Disk Image". I've downloaded the "Live CD", but the VMPlayer couldn't create a new machine. Ive tried several samples from the internet, using the following methods:

1. Create it as Ubuntu.
2. Create it as a 2.6.x kernel.
3. Create a blank VM and point the HD to the .iso file.

I keep getting" "Failed to mount RW root filesystem" and then there's a 120 seconds suspension before a reboot (which causes the same error). The screen shot of the log (Alt+F3):

What am I missing?

Comment: I just booted that liveCD in VMware and it worked fine.  (You said "point the HD to the .iso file", but you really meant "point the virtual CD drive to the .iso file", right?)

Comment: BTW, in the link that you gave there is no 'ChromeOS'. It's more a custom linux version with chrome in it. For ChromeOS - check here: http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/ or built it from the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the link you've shared there is no .vmdk (and I couldn't find it around the web). So if I were in your shoes I would go to: http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-guide#TOC-Building-Chromium-OS
and try to built it with the spec (cpu, mem etc') that you have on the VMPlayer.
Another option is to try and install a built that someone did: http://www.tomshardware.com/news/chrome-os-google-vmware-download,9124.html

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Chrome OS by deploying ready-to-use [Chrome OS VMs by hexxeh.](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/)